# Why shared_ptr<T> expects copy/move constructor in T?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I have the following code:

```c
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename U> class A;

template<typename U>
class B
{
    private:
        shared_ptr<const A<U>> _a;
    public:
        B (shared_ptr<const A<U>> __a) {
            _a = __a;
        }
};

template<typename U>
class A
{
    public:
        B<U> foo () const {
            return { make_shared<const A<U>> (this) };
        }
};

int
main ()
{
    A<int> a;
    B<int> b = a.foo ();

    return 0;
}
```

G++ 4.8.0 and Clang 3.3svn report that the class `A` hasn't a copy or move constructor. For
example, G++ print the following message:

```
/home/alessio/Programmi/GCC/include/c++/4.8.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: no      matching function for call to ‘A<int>::A(const A<int>* const)’
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
  ^
/home/alessio/Programmi/GCC/include/c++/4.8.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: note:  candidates are:
prova.cpp:19:7: note: constexpr A<int>::A()
 class A
       ^
prova.cpp:19:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
prova.cpp:19:7: note: constexpr A<int>::A(const A<int>&)
prova.cpp:19:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const A<int>* const’ to    ‘const A<int>&’
prova.cpp:19:7: note: constexpr A<int>::A(A<int>&&)
prova.cpp:19:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const A<int>* const’ to  ‘A<int>&&’
```

What is the reason?

Comment: `A` isn't a class. It's a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, `make_shared` constructs a new instance of given type ant then wraps it into shared_ptr. You are trying to construct a new instance of A with type A*. It's `shared_ptr`'s constructor that takes a pointer as an argument, not `make_shared`.

Comment: But how `make_shared` constructs the new instance? You suppose that in `A` class there is a private field `C c`; if in `A` class there isn't any copy/move constructor, how it constructs the new instance?

Comment: `make_shared` calls a constructor of `A` class. The constructor is selected according to parameters of `make_shared` (of course, the object must be constructible in a specified way). If you want to create a `shared_ptr` pointing to an existing object with a private (forbidden) copy constructor, you should use `shared_ptr`'s constructor directly, like `shared_ptr<const A<U> >(this)`. Note that in your case you still have the default copy constructor for class `A`, so you may as well write `make_shared<const A<U> >(*this)` thus creating a copy.

Answer (score 5):

You need to say:

```
return { make_shared<const A<U>>(*this) };
//                              ^^^
```